# context.SaveChanges() doing something else besides expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I started working on a project in my work that doesn't have any documentation, and the person who developed the project in the first place isn't avalaible anymore.

There is this piece of code for doing and update to the database

```
_report = db.Report.Where(x => x.IdReport == ReportId).FirstOrDefault();
db.Report.Attach(_report);
_report.attr1 = reportmodel.attr1;
_report.attr2 = reportmodel.attr2;
_report.attr3 = reportmodel.attr3;
if (db.SaveChanges() != 0)
{
   return View(reportmodel)
}
```

Looks fine and indeed does the update to the database in the table "Report", but additionally it is being inserted in another table "ReportLog" the detail of the change (orginal value, new value), I believe this is being done somehow in the SaveChanges().

So my question is where can I find where those insertions to the log table are being executed?

I have checked in the model if the table "Report" has some stored procedure mapped in the update action, checked for triggers and stored procedures in the database and used Find(Ctrl+f) to check for "ReportLog" in the entire solution, but I couldn't find where the insertion is being executed.

And something really weird is that this happens for the "Report" table only, using SaveChanges() for other updates in other tables does only what is expected

Comment: Look for [interceptors](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx)

Comment: I used (Ctrl+F) to look for "interceptor" in the entire solution, there are no results

Comment: Beside interceptors, you can check if someone has  `public override int SaveChanges()` . Your 'attach' seems to be useless/not necessary but a check for null is missing.

Comment: No, there are no results looking for "int SaveChanges", the check for null i don´t think is necesary because the ReportId is being directly retrieved from bd and there is a check for the id having a value

Comment: On the database, try checking for triggers on the "Report" table

Comment: My first instinct is a database trigger given that you can't find any responsible code.

Comment: Finally found it, it was a trigger on the table, and i was looking for triggers in the Programmability section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a trigger on the Report table that was doing the inserts